# Is it possible to create a live folder with out a sql connection? (android api)

Tags: android, android-livefolders

I've been reading http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/live-folders.html
and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/LiveFolders.html
and https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/+/donut-release/src/com/android/contacts/ContactsLiveFolders.java

But I want to extend my app (Which is a listview) to a live folder. It would be a nice fit. How do i use my listadapter as a cursor? Is this possible? And past that, how do i set the similar getView that my Listadapter provides? is a Baseadapter, which my listadapter inherits, able to become a cursor, which a livefolder needs?

Comment: If you want to be helped, consider accepting some answers people give you.

Comment: okay i went back and accepted. I didn't know you had to do that.

Comment: without sql ? hmmm so where you're storing data ?

Comment: Data is currently stored in memory

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. But you need a ContentProvider. While a ContentProvider is usually backed by some sql database, it is not an requirement. You can get the data in the ContentProvider's query() method from any source, as long as you return it as cursor. If you dont have a database cursor, you can wrap your data in a MatrixCursor instead and return the MatrixCursor.
I have such an implementation of the query() method and it works by returning a MatrixCursor.

It is a common misunderstanding that ContentProvider need to be backed up by datebase queries.
It is better to understand the ContentProvider as a contract which specifies 4 different (CRUD) methods which take certain types of arguments and return certain types.

Additionally, you can have different queries inside these 4 methods and switch them depending on the Uri.

Used like that ContentProviders can use any datasource and perforn any operation on that datasource, as long as you adhere to the contract specifiied by the ContentProvider class. That makes them extremely powerful.